# C++: Post ++ operator overload after an assignment operator

Tags: c++

<sup>*Please note, that this question relates to an assignment for school.*</sup>

We are building a custom Fraction class with most operators being overloaded. Most of them are not giving me problems. However, this part of the driver is not working for me:

```
cout << "testing post++ with f2 = f1++;" << '\n';
f2 = f1++;
cout << "f1 : " << f1 << '\n';
cout << "f2 : " << f2 << '\n';
assert(f1 == Fraction(6));
assert(f2 == Fraction(5));
cout << "ok\n\n";
```

What happens is that f2 gets assigned the value of f1++ and not pre-incremented f1, which is what the assert assumes should be there.

[image]

My operator looks like:

```
Fraction Fraction::operator++(int a)
{
    numer = (numer + denom);
    normalize();
    return *this;
}
```

Now, I'm scratching my head over this because in my head the logic is that ++ has precedence over the assignment operator, so I'd have expected the asserts to test f1 and f2 with the same values for a post++ operation. For the ++pre overload, the assert values are equal to each other in the driver.

My question is, why should f2 take the pre-incremented value of f1, and how could I modify my operators to achieve this, or could this be an error from the prof?

Assignment operator:

```
Fraction& Fraction::operator=(const Fraction &rhs) {
    numer = rhs.getNumer();
    denom = rhs.getDenom();
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: [related FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/), see "unary arithmetic operators" heading

Comment: Hint: `a++` should return the value of `a` ***before*** you modify it. Thus `return *this;` is a no-no for the implementation.

Comment: btw, in addition to my answer, why in the world do you actually take the trouble and post a *screenshot* of the output rather than just copying the text from the command-line window?

Comment: T operator ++(int) { T tmp(*this); ++(*this); return tmp; }

Comment: @ChristianHackl because ... I like using my macro that uploads a portion of screen to imgur? :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have problems with overloaded operators as in your example, it's often helpful to look behind the syntactic sugar and see what the calls "really" look like.

`f2 = f1++;`

This one actually translates as:

```
f2.operator=(f1.operator++(0));
```

It's even clearer if you assume for one moment that these are really just ordinarily named functions:

```
f2.Assign(f1.PostIncrement());
```

Now it should be obvious what happens. Your `PostIncrement` function is called first, and its result is passed as an argument to `Assign`.

There is nothing magic about overloaded operators. They are just functions with special names. There are no special rules for returning values or passing arguments. Thus,

```
Fraction Fraction::operator++(int a)
{
    numer = (numer + denom);
    normalize();
    return *this;
}
```

, imagined like this:

```
Fraction Fraction::PostIncrement()
{
    numer = (numer + denom);
    normalize();
    return *this;
}
```

does exactly what you wrote: It increments itself, then returns itself.

If you want the same post-increment semantics as the built-in types, then you have to **implement those semantics manually**. In your `operator++(int)`, create a temporary copy of `*this` first, then increment, *then* return the temporary copy.

Comment: Thank you for the clear in-depth answer. Makes sense now. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Post-increment returns a value *before* the increment. That is why when you see `return *this` in a postfix `++` or `--` operator you should immediately know that the implementation is wrong.

The correct sequence of actions is as follows:

- Make a copy of `*this`
- Do the increment
- Return the copy.

Assuming that your `Fraction` class has a properly functioning copy constructor, the fix is very easy:

```
Fraction Fraction::operator++(int a)
{
    Fraction res(*this);
    // The following two lines are most likely shared with the prefix ++
    // A common trick is to call ++*this here, to avoid code duplication.
    numer = (numer + denom);
    normalize();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear and correct answer. Have a great weekend. :)